# set customer on a production order

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

when I create a production order I want to add a combobox that contain the list of customer
the goal is to choose the production order for any customer

please how can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you have to add a new field to table `ProdTable` with extended data type `CustAccount`. Then you have to customize form `ProdTableCreate` and add the new field to the form.

That said I encourage you to look into how Dynamics AX settles requirements from a customer sales order with a production order. This would give you the same information and would not require setting the customer manually when creating the production.